# Update with Zend_DB on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework, sql-update, zend-db

I am using Zend Framework. I have tree tables. Users and Groups and one table linking them.

I want to increment a field from users of a given group. To increment one User I do:

```
$table = 'users';
$update = array(
    'ACLVersion' => new Zend_Db_Expr('ACLVersion + 1')
);
$where[] = $db->quoteInto('id = ?', $user);
$db->update($table, $update, $where);
```

I tried to use multiple wheres.

I have no clue how to join the tables in a where with Zend.

Answer (score 0):

To use a `JOIN` with `Zend_Db_Table`, you have to disable the integrity check.

See example #27 in the [ZF Reference Guide for `Zend_Db_Table`](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html):

```
  $table = new Bugs();
  // retrieve with from part set, important when joining
  $select = $table->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);
  $select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
         ->where('bug_status = ?', 'NEW')
         ->join('accounts', 'accounts.account_name = bugs.reported_by')
         ->where('accounts.account_name = ?', 'Bob');
  $rows = $table->fetchAll($select);
```

Note that disabling the integrity check will also disable some of the automagic of the resulting recordset:

> The resulting row or rowset will be
>   returned as a 'locked' row (meaning
>   the save(), delete() and any
>   field-setting methods will throw an
>   exception).

Answer (score -1):

Load $num with a array of id's from a given group

The following code will do the job

```
$table = 'users';
$update = array(
    'ACLVersion' => new Zend_Db_Expr('ACLVersion + 1')
);
$where = $db->quoteInto('id IN (?)', $num);
$db->update($table, $update, $where);
```